# Print stops in HP LaserJet M1126nw MFP with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I'm installing a new USB printer HP LaserJet Pro M126Nw on a laptop. The printer is installed but when I print a document it's getting stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the printer you just installed. Confirm you have the packages `hplip` and `hplip-gui` installed. If not install them from a terminal:

```
sudo apt install hplip hplip-gui
```

Then from a terminal run:

```
sudo hp-setup -i
```

Follow the setup instructions and your printer should then be set up.